# Recording LP Records

Tags: recording

I have over 400 LP records.  About half of them are classical, many of which are European imports (such as DDG, Das Alte Werk, Argo, and Seraphim).  Many of my LPs are also jazz (such as Ellington, Davis, Getz, and Modern Jazz Quartet).

Question:  what kind of turntable should I purchase by which I can not only listen to my records but record them?  Would something like an Audio-Technica turntable for about $125 be better than a direct drive turntable (for $255)?  I would be using Bose and Audio-Technica headphones to do the recording, as I have a hearing loss.  I am on a limited budget.  This would be for my own personal use.

Comment: Recommendation questions generally get answers that are entirely subjective in nature. Technology recommendations have problems with quickly becoming obsolete. As a result, I am closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of turntables with cheap built in usb digital to analog converters that can be used to record to your computer.  None of them are particularly stellar, but will do the job fine enough.

I would suggest the Project Elemental Phono USB.  Project is a company that makes very high end tables costing thousands of dollars and their budget models are considered the best bang for the buck by most.  Audio Technica turntables on the other hand are outsourced Chinese OEM models.

http://www.project-audio.com/main.php?prod=elementalphonousb&cat=turntables&lang=en